# Is it possible to save a selection of vertices?

Tags: selection-tools

I finished selecting intricate parts of an object in edit mode (made the mistake of linking them), similar to having spent half an hour lasso-ing an object in Photoshop. Is it possible to save this selection so next time I launch Blender the selection's still there?

Comment: You can assign the vertices to a vertex group.

Comment: Rather than manually selecting you can press `L` to select vertices linked to the vertex under the cursor. `P` will separate into new objects by selected vertices or loose parts.

Answer (score 2):

You could add the selection to a vertex group so the next time you need the vertices to be selected you just need to to click on Select for the current vertex Group